# How get class name from 'this' reference in jquery

Tags: jquery, class, jquery-selectors

I want to know how can I get the class name of an element from `this` reference.
I have following HTML element

```
<input type="checkbox" class="NotSelected @placeholderString" onchange="SaveCompairedOffers(this);">
```

**jQuery code**

```
function SaveCompairedOffers(obj) {
    //Hiding irrelevant code from here

    AddCompareOfferInCompareBox();
}
```

In the AddCompareOfferInCompareBox function I want to append class name of the object on `compare-box` class.

```
function AddCompareOfferInCompareBox()
{
    var innerHtml = "";
    $('.SelectedOffer').each(function () 
        //append class name of current passed object to this div
        innerHtml = innerHtml + '<div class="compare-box"></div>';
    });
    $(".AddCompareOfferByMe").html(innerHtml);
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: which class name? I guess `@placeholderString`?

Comment: @Satpal yes exactly

Comment: $(this).attr("class") gives NotSelected @placeholderString

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use `data-*` prefixed attribute to store arbitrary data.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="NotSelected" data-str="@placeholderString" onchange="SaveCompairedOffers(this);">
```

This can be fetched using [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property

> The HTMLElement.dataset property allows access, both in reading and writing mode, to all the custom data attributes (data-*) set on the element. It is a map of DOMString, one entry for each custom data attribute.

```
function SaveCompairedOffers(obj){
   var str =  obj.dataset.str;
   AddCompareOfferInCompareBox(str );
}

function AddCompareOfferInCompareBox(str)   {       
    $('.SelectedOffer').each(function () 
        $('<div></div>', {
           "class" : "compare-box " + str
        }).appentTo(".AddCompareOfferByMe");        
    });
}
```

---

However if you still want to use class name, then [Element.className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) property can be used.

> className gets and sets the value of the class attribute of the specified element.

*usage*

```
function SaveCompairedOffers(obj){
   var str =  obj.className;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to this is vanilla javascript. In your function, where you want to reference `this`, add the following code to assign your classes to a variable:

```
var classes = this.className
```

If you want to get an array of all classes, you can achieve this by using the split() function, like the following:

```
var classes = this.className.split(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the actual question, how to get the css class assigned to an object from a jQuery reference to it, try this:

`var elementClass = ($(myselector).prop('className');`